# Load local Html file doesn't refer the js file in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, ios, uiwebview

I am working with `UIWebView` project and I want to load an HTML file from a project resource. It is working fine when I run from the URL, but when I view the HTML file locally, JS files are not loaded. Loading the local HTML local file doesn't refer to js files in `UIWebView`.

Here's my code to load the HTML file project local resource and does't refer the js file:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"textfile" ofType:@"txt"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

NSString *path1 = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath];
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path1];
NSLog(@"%@  >>> %@",baseURL,path);

[webview loadHTMLString:string baseURL:baseURL];
```

This code doesn't find JS files in `UIWebView`, even though it loads image files from the project resource successfully.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i am find the problem is js files are not automatically copy to project bundles so, you can try follow instructions like below:

go to your project **target** -> click tab to **Bulid Phases** -> expand the section **copy Bundle Resources** -> now find all files bin bundle resources of your project check your js files not copied,so, click + button and add js files manually on your project!

now run the project working perfectly!

like below screen shot:

[image]

after add js file in your project below screen shot:

[image]

welcome!